# Modal positioning in css grid system

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to centrally position a modal whose button is clicked in grid column 2. Can anyone please point me in the right direction. I wouldn't want to hard code any margins ofcourse (responsive).

Right now it (green div) is only showing up / restricted to grid-column 2 as seen below .

[image]

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
height: 100%;
margin: 10px;
```

```js
class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    isShowModal: false
  };

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isShowModal: true })
  }

  render() {
    const { isShowModal } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="grid-1">
        </div>
        <div className="grid-2">
        {isShowModal && <Modal />}
          <div className="add">
            <button onClick={() => this.openModal()} type="button">Open modal</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a minimal example showing your modal behavior. At the moment, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: share ur code here so we can clearify what's wrong

Comment: I think `absolute` `position`ing from the `left` `calc(50% - modal width)` can be a reasonable approach.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi I tried that but the parent (relative) would be `grid-2`

Comment: Then from the `left` `modal width / 2` with higher `z-index`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think what you are looking for is Width max-content with some padding and margin 0px auto.

```
margin: 0px auto;
width: max-content;
padding: 10px;
max-width:100%; //for responsive purposes.
```

Then make a surrounding div and position it fixed. And apply the above styles to the divs inside your surrounding div

What this is doing is making a surrounding div that you can design your stuff inside of that will be centered.

Side Note: If you div is falling underneath other elements just set the z-index to 1.

```
z-index:1;
```